# jQuery Rotating Wheel Menu

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know of a plugin for jQuery that emulates a sort of rotating wheel system?

Comment: Can you provide an example? Is this a wheel like what you mean: http://tapbots.com/convertbot/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This link is still in development, but are you talking about a Carousel type plugin like this?

[jQuery UI Labs Carousel](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3843/branches/labs/carousel/demo/dynamic.html)

Right now it is in development and is in a subversion repository, if you are familiar with subversion you can run this command (I tested this on a Mac, not sure how it should be worded on a Windows machine)

```
svn checkout http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/carousel jquery-carousel
```

Be sure to test it out in different browsers, I am not sure of its level of completeness.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am talking about!

Comment: So ...where in the world can we get this? :O

Comment: Its in a subversion repository, are you on a Mac or a PC?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the [jQuery Carousel](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/3843/branches/labs/carousel/demo/) in this original answer was moved to

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3843/branches/labs/carousel/demo/index.html

You can download the js from http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3843/branches/labs/carousel/ui.carousel.js but it clearly says "- for experimental use only -"

The closest plugin that I found is this http://pixelcone.com/jquery/jquery-rotating-menu which has a rotating menu.

Below are few other actively maintained similar plugins,

- Responsive Carousel - https://github.com/filamentgroup/responsive-carousel
- rcarousel: https://github.com/ryrych/rcarousel
- jCarousel: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/
- Richard Scarrott's: https://github.com/richardscarrott/jquery-ui-carousel/

Answer (score 2):

check out jQuery Radmenu - http://www.tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for ?

http://www.antiyes.com/rotate-image-javascript

http://wilq32.googlepages.com/wilq32.rollimage222

Comment: Hrnm. I meant more like a menu where the items would rotate in a circle, or behind other items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experimenting the possibility of flash like rotating menu in jquery. I don't really know if I'm doing the right thing. check it out here. http://pixelcone.com/jquery/jquery-rotating-menu

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[jQuery Rotating Wheel Menu Plugin](http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/rotating-wheel.php)

This has a rotating wheel, moved by user's mouse, of text that can, of course be clickable.